# sqlite3 square brackets in a select statement

Tags: sqlite

In the following piece of code, what is the purpose of the square?

```
SELECT Value, [Default] AS Selected FROM SKUOptVal WHERE SKUOptID = ?
```

Cheers.

This code is written for SQLite3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an identifier. It's the same as saying "Default". It's included for compatibility with MS Access. Since `Default` is a keyword in SQL, it needs to be quoted if used as an identifier, as it is here.

Answer (score 3):

The column is named default, which is the same as an SQL keyword.  Thus, the brackets are used to denote we are referring to the column default and not the keyword default.